# NoUISlider Tooltip only show integers

Tags: javascript, integer, tooltip, nouislider

I want that the tooltip on my slider only shows integers like "130" and not "130.00".
I just dont know where i could start.

Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var groesseslider = document.getElementById('slider-tooltip');

noUiSlider.create(groesseslider, {
    start: [ 145 ],
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': 100,
        'max': 250
    }
});
    });
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var groesseslider = document.getElementById('slider-tooltip');
var tipHandles = groesseslider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-handle'),
    tooltips = [];

// Add divs to the slider handles.
for ( var i = 0; i < tipHandles.length; i++ ){
    tooltips[i] = document.createElement('div');
    tipHandles[i].appendChild(tooltips[i]);
}

// When the slider changes, write the value to the tooltips.
groesseslider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ){
    tooltips[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];
});
    });
```

My JS Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/miiauwz/66a5ahm0/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Most preferable way (TL;DR):

[manually formatting](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/number-formatting/):

```
var sliderFormat = document.getElementById('slider-format');

noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
    start: [ 20 ],

    /*...*/

    format: {
      to: function ( value ) {
        // format as you like / need:
        return value + ',-'; // or value.toFixed();
      },
      from: function ( value ) {
        // format as you like / need:
        return value.replace(',-', '');
      }
    }
});
```

---

### Original complete answer

You can either try using the `unencoded` value like described in noUISlider's documentation about [events and their binding](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-binding)

```
slider.noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle, unencoded ) {
    // values: Current slider values;
    // handle: Handle that caused the event;
    // unencoded: Slider values without formatting;
});
```

or another possibility would be using the [format option on slider creation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-formatting) (but haven't tried it myself yet):

```
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [ 20000 ],
    ...
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0, // default is 2
        thousand: '.', // thousand delimiter
        postfix: ' (US $)', // gets appended after the number
    })
});
```

The drawback is you have to download the wNumb-Library separately from here: [http://refreshless.com/wnumb/](https://refreshless.com/wnumb/).

---

**Another way without wNumb**

After having another look at the examples from noUISlider, I found [this way](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) for manually formatting (at the bottom of the page):

```
var sliderFormat = document.getElementById('slider-format');

noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
    start: [ 20 ],
    ...

    format: {
      to: function ( value ) {
        return value + ',-';
      },
      from: function ( value ) {
        return value.replace(',-', '');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it wont work,
i got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: wNumb is not defined

and the the unencoded method doest change anything :/

Comment: @Juloius did you try to access the unencoded value like this: `unencoded[handle]` ?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with "acces" the value, im very new to Javascript, sorry

Comment: Thank you!, i downloaded the wnumb library and it works :)

Comment: @Juloius In case you are interested in the other two methods besides using wNumb, here is a jsfiddle using the unencoded value: [http://jsfiddle.net/499Lg1bz/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/499Lg1bz/8/) and one using the manual `from`- and `to`-methods: [http://jsfiddle.net/499Lg1bz/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/499Lg1bz/11/)

Answer (score 29):

This can work..

```
var sliderFormat = document.getElementById('slider-format');

noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
start: [ 20 ],
...
format: {
    from: function(value) {
            return parseInt(value);
        },
    to: function(value) {
            return parseInt(value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice to have a solution that doesn't require an additional dependency, as the library is supposed to be "minimal"

Comment: The best solution so far

Comment: Great solution, no need to add wNum or modify the library  just to remove decimals. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! This is certainly the way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't think you'll ever need to have decimal places on your site, you can search the jquery.nouislider.min.js file for `toFixed(2)` and replace with `toFixed(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want to use wNumb - library , this method might work.
This will give you value without decimals.
Hope this helps.

```js
value.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account Rounding

Answer (score 1):

Possible way without using any other library. If we want to show only integers there is no need to use additional libraries. Assuming that in the html code there is the element 'slider-fee'.

```html
<div id="slider-fee"></div>
```

Let's say that we want to give the possibility to choose a range of hours in a day. Something like 7h-19h or 8h-20h and in the tooltip we want to display the integer only.

```
dragTapSlider = document.getElementById('slider-fee');

// number of decimal places 
decimals = 0;

// format object
numberFormat = {
    // 'to' the formatted value. Receives a number.
    to: function (value) {
        return value.toFixed(decimals);
    },
    // 'from' the formatted value.
    // Receives a string, should return a number.
    from: function (value) {
        return Number(value);;
    }
};

noUiSlider.create(dragTapSlider, {
    start: [8, 20],
    connect: [false, true, false], 
    step: 1,
    behaviour: 'drag',
    tooltips: [true, true],
    range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 24
    },
    format: numberFormat
});
```

[noUiSlider - Integer Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uCL0.png)

Example for money range

```
dragTapSlider = document.getElementById('slider-fee');

decimals = 2;
suffix = '€';

numberFormat = {
    // 'to' Format the value to currency.
    to: function (value) {
        return value.toFixed(decimals) + ' ' + suffix;
    },
    // 'from' Convert currency value to number.
    // Receives a string, should return a number.
    from: function (value) {
        return Number(value.replace(' ' + suffix));
    }
};

noUiSlider.create(dragTapSlider, {

    start: [25, 40],
    connect: [false, true, false],
    step: 0.5,
    behaviour: 'drag',
    tooltips: [true, true],
    range: {
        'min': 20,
        'max': 50
    },
    format: numberFormat
});
```

[noUiSlider - Currency Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coa63.png)

Comment: add some description to your answer so that it is more understandable and the user gets an idea what the code is doing

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd provide an answer in case someone else comes looking for this. Simply add the following as an option to the noUiSlider creation:

```
tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 0 }), wNumb({ decimals: 0 }) ],
```

The following code will create the slider you need with the noUiSlider tooltip displaying only the integer value with no decimal points:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var groesseslider = document.getElementById('slider-tooltip');

noUiSlider.create(groesseslider, {
    start: [ 145 ],
    step: 1,
    tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 0 }), wNumb({ decimals: 0 }) ],
    range: {
        'min': 100,
        'max': 250
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var skipSlider = document.getElementById('price');

noUiSlider.create(skipSlider, {
    start: [47000, 247000],
    connect: true,
    behaviour: 'drag',
    step: 1,
    range: {
      'min': [47000],
      'max': [247000]
    },
});

var skipValues = [
    document.getElementById('min-price'),
    document.getElementById('max-price')
];

skipSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle, unencoded) {
    skipValues[handle].innerHTML = unencoded[handle];
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: ordinary thing is a step and a handle

Answer (score 0):

Just use Math for this instead of the library.

```
Math.round(value)
```

Comment: value is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

React example with no external library:

```
<Nouislider
    range={{ min: 0, max: 5 }}
    tooltips={true}
    step={1}
    start={[0, 5]}
    connect
    format={{
      from: (value) => {
        return parseInt(value);
      },
      to: (value) => {
        return parseInt(value);
      }
    }}
    onSlide={onUpdate}
/>
```